# Sklearn pipeline and custom transformers to remove specific value from columns

Tags: scikit-learn, preprocessing, pipelines

I'm trying to use sklearn pipelines and custom transformers to do outlier removal. What I want to do is identify outliers using an IQR-filter, set the outlier values to 'OUTLIER' (not NaN), and then remove all 'OUTLIER' values in the numerical columns. The reason for setting the otulier values to 'OUTLIER' instead of NaN is because I want to impute existing NaN values while removing outlier values. The pipeline would then be `IQR-filter, remove outliers, impute missing values, standard scaler`.

What I've tried are the following custom transformers:

```
class FeatureSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, feature_names):
        self.feature_names = feature_names
        
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
        
    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.feature_names]

class IQRFilter(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self,factor=2):
        self.factor = factor
        
    def outlier_detector(self,X,y=None):
        X = pd.Series(X).copy()
        q1 = X.quantile(0.25)
        q3 = X.quantile(0.75)
        iqr = q3 - q1
        self.lower_bound.append(q1 - (self.factor * iqr))
        self.upper_bound.append(q3 + (self.factor * iqr))

    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        self.lower_bound = []
        self.upper_bound = []
        X.apply(self.outlier_detector)
        return self
    
    def transform(self,X,y=None):
        X = pd.DataFrame(X).copy()
        for i in range(X.shape[1]):
            x = X.iloc[:, i].copy()
            x[(x < self.lower_bound[i]) | (x > self.upper_bound[i])] = 'OUTLIER'
            X.iloc[:, i] = x
        return X

class RemoveIQROutliers(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X):
        return X.loc[X != 'OUTLIER']
```

And the following pipeline:

```
numerical_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('FeatureSelector', FeatureSelector(num_cols)),
    ('iqr_filter', IQRFilter()),
    ('remove_outliers', RemoveIQROutliers()),
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler())
])
```

However, runnning `numerical_pipeline.fit_transform(X_train)` results in this error output:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\usert~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_21276/3029174893.py in <module>
----> 1 numerical_pipeline.fit_transform(X_train)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    412         """
    413         fit_params_steps = self._check_fit_params(**fit_params)
--> 414         Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    415 
    416         last_step = self._final_estimator

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    334                 cloned_transformer = clone(transformer)
    335             # Fit or load from cache the current transformer
--> 336             X, fitted_transformer = fit_transform_one_cached(
    337                 cloned_transformer,
    338                 X,

c:\anaconda3\envs\datascience\lib\site-packages\joblib\memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    347 
    348     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 349         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    350 
    351     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):
...
-> 5842                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   5843 
   5844             not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())

KeyError: "None of [Index([                                                            ('l', 'i', 'n', 'e', '_', 'n', 'o'),\n                                                    ('p', 'a', 'r', 't', '_', 'p', 'r', 'i', 'c', 'e'),\n                                               ('b', 'u', 'y', '_', 'q', 't', 'y', '_', 'd', 'u', 'e'),\n                 ('l', 'i', 'n', 'e', '_', 't', 'o', 't', 'a', 'l', '_', 'w', 'e', 'i', 'g', 'h', 't'),\n                                                                                  ('c', 'o', 's', 't'),\n                                                              ('d', 'i', 's', 'c', 'o', 'u', 'n', 't'),\n                                ('p', 'o', 'r', 't', '_', 'l', 'e', 'a', 'd', '_', 't', 'i', 'm', 'e'),\n                                                    ('d', 'e', 'a', 'd', 'w', 'e', 'i', 'g', 'h', 't'),\n       ('v', 'a', 'l', 'u', 'e', '_', 'u', 's', 'd', '_', 's', 'p', 'o', 't', '_', 'l', 'i', 'n', 'e')],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

**Edit:**
X_train.info():

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 13400 entries, 1993441 to 1970783
Data columns (total 20 columns):
 #   Column               Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------               --------------  -----  
 0   X1                   13400 non-null  float64
 1   X2                   13400 non-null  float64
 2   X3                   13400 non-null  float64
 3   X4                   13181 non-null  float64
 4   X5                   13400 non-null  float64
 5   X6                   13400 non-null  float64
 6   X7                   13209 non-null  float64
 7   X8                   11956 non-null  float64
 8   X9                   13400 non-null  float64
 9   X10                  13400 non-null  object 
 10  X11                  13400 non-null  object 
 11  X12                  13191 non-null  object 
 12  X13                  11999 non-null  object 
 13  X14                  13380 non-null  object 
 14  X15                  13400 non-null  object 
 15  X16                  13400 non-null  object 
 16  X17                  11976 non-null  object 
 17  X18                  11976 non-null  object 
 18  X19                  13367 non-null  object 
 19  X20                  13400 non-null  object 
dtypes: float64(9), object(11)
memory usage: 2.1+ MB
```

Comment: Welcome to the Data Science SE Community. A quick question in regards to the OP. Do you mind sharing a snippet of the training dataset ? Does it have all Numerical Variables or a mix of Num and Cat ?

Comment: Thanks @Polymath ! I've included the output of `X_train.info()` in the original post. As you can see the numerical columns (X1-X9) are only floats or NaNs, wheras the categorical columns (X10-X20) are objects. Of course, after the IQR-filter step in the pipeline, some of the values in the numerical columns are set to 'OUTLIER' and thus are not purely floats anymore.

Comment: and you are importing the columns (X10-20) in the pipeline ? As looking at the key-error, seems like these  string/Cat columns might be the cause of that

Comment: Yes, as you can see from the first step in the pipeline `('FeatureSelector', FeatureSelector(num_cols)` selects the numerical columns (`num_cols`) which simply is `num_cols = ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', ....]`

Comment: I believe the error comes from wrong logic in the `class RemoveIQROutliers`, specifically the `transform` method, but I don't quite know how to fix it.

Comment: Are the column names '[Line', 'No', 'Part', 'Price'.... ]. I have a hunch that the column name imported in the X-dataframe seem to be different that what comes up in data.info(). You sure you are using the same df with the same column names (X1, X2...) as data.info() / what's used in the previous methods in the final pipeline

Comment: Oh, yes. I changed the column names in the output of X_train.info() manually for confidentiality (they are not confidential, but just wanted to disguise it a little bit). I realize they are shown in the error output, but they are the same! Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think I got it to work now actually. Changed `RemoveIQROutliers.transform` to `def transform(self, X):
        for col in X.columns:
            X = X[X[col] != 'OUTLIER']
        return X` 

Very simple pandas logic fix really..